# Using logic for ngIf within HTML or use a variable in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

Within our application we have to show/hide a button depending on some logic.
What is a better place to define this logic (and why) ?
In Html:

```
*ngIf='here goes the logic' 
//Or 
*ngIf='someBoolean' and in typeScript someBoolean = 'here goes the logic'.
```

Comment: It depends on what "better" means to you. It also depends on the complexity of the logic, what it depends on, when the value changes, etc. Make things correct. Then make things readable. Then make things testable. Then make things faster if you have a performance problem and if you can prove that it comes from there.

Comment: Yes, you are correct that the term better is vague. 

1. Complexity of logic: (it's a onliner not very complex)
2. When the value changes: (After the ngInit it will not change anymore)

Code is working and also readable. I'm not sure about the testability. 

Anyways, thanks for the quick reply for now i guess i leave the code in html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting the logic for `ngIf` in `HTML` is not a good idea. 
That logic will be evaluated every time there is a slight change. If the logic is complex, it might be a performance concern. 
I would suggest using a variable whenever it is possible.